# En général, en fait (in general, in fact)

Tags: adverbes, coordination

> Although Eq. 4.1, as a vector equation, requires that the acceleration
>   vector have the same direction as the resultant external force,
>   it does not follow that the resultant force necessarily passes through mass center. **In general, in fact,** it does not pass through mass center, as will be shown later.
>
> Bien que Éq. 4.1, en tant qu’équation vectorielle, exige que l’accélération
>   ait la même direction que la force externe résultante,
>   il ne s'ensuit pas que la force résultante passe nécessairement par le centre de masse. En général, en fait, elle ne passe pas par le centre de masse, comme on le verra plus loin.

Peut-on employer la construction **En général, en fait,** comme ci-dessus ?

Comment: Je supprimerais  « En général, » pour ne garder que « En fait, elle ne passe ... »

Comment: pour info "acceleration vector" --> vecteur d'accélération (parfois aussi vecteur accélération ou, tout simplement, accélération) / exige que + subjonctif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans ce cas présent, même si ce type de formulation est rare, je pense que la construction peut s'employer. Les deux notions sont en effet bien distinctes (et nécessaires pour la bonne compréhension de la phrase).

> En général = quelque chose qui arrive souvent (mais pas toujours)
>
> En fait = permet d'insister sur un événement qui arrive alors qu'on
>   pourrait s'attendre au contraire.

Supprimer "en général" reviendrait à dire que la force vectorielle ne passe jamais par le centre de masse, ce qui est faux. Supprimer "en fait" enlève le lien avec la phrase précédente, ce qui complique la compréhension.

Toutefois, la double mise en avant n'est pas conseillée car elle alourdit le texte. Je propose donc la phrase suivante (sans changer le sens du texte)

> En fait, elle ne passe généralement pas par le centre de masse...

Answer (score 2):

Il faudrait tout d'abord que le début de votre traduction soit légèrement ajusté:

Bien que Eq. 4/1, en tant qu’équation vectorielle, exige que le vecteur d'accélération ait la même direction que la force externe résultante,[and so on]

It seems quite natural to keep "en fait" on the condition of placing it first and placing "général" somewhere else; you can thus keep the  indication inherent in the English, that is the indication that the situation is really different from what could be elicited from the first sentence.

- En fait, elle ne passe pas, en général, par le centre de masse…
- En fait, en général, elle ne passe pas par le centre de masse…
- En fait, elle ne passe en général pas par le centre de masse…

Comment: @radouxju Elle me semble correcte et je ne pensais pas du tout qu'il puisse y avoir un problème, mais vous pourriez avoir raison.

Comment: @radouxju  Il y cependant qqc d'étrange dans votre commentaire en cela que vous fournissez pratiquement la même phrase: tout ce qui change c'est que « en général » devient « généralement ».

Comment: @radouxju Il me semble maintenant qu'il y avait vraiment quelque chose dans votre commentaire; merci.

Comment: il me semble que "en général" se place comme "généralement" dans une phrase négative (dans ma phrase, c'est "généralement pas"). Donc sa "bonne" place est dans la troisième phrase (que vous venez d'ajouter. Lorsque "en général" est déplacé (mis en évidence), je pense qu'il faut mettre une virgule. J'aurais donc tendance à écrire "En fait, en général, elle ...".

Comment: @radouxju Cette tendance qui est la votre ne me semble pas passible de critique; je n'insiste pas moi-même sur la version sans virgule.